# AIR framework move window using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, air

I'm building and AIR framework application using HTML and JavaScript/jQuery in Aptana 2.0. I've removed the toolbox (<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>), but I need to enable the user to move the window around.

I want to be able to click on any control on the window or the window itself and move the window.

I've found some examples for doing this in ActionScript, but it didn't help much as I need to do this in HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think there's any difference. You listen to mouse down and then you listen to mouse move. Can't see any reason why it would be different using AS and JS.

Comment: @Pavelfljōt: I expected the same, but I just don't get how to make it work in JS... Care to give me an example?

Comment: google is your friend, there are really tons of examples. "JavaScript mouse events"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we need is to handle the mouse down event and while the mouse is pressed, call the `startMove()` method of the `nativeWindow` object making that window to follow the mouse.

```
// bind the mouse down event
$(document).bind
(
    "mousedown",
    function ()
    {
        // this will make the window to follow the mouse
        nativeWindow.startMove();
    }
);
```